# Rename a file that multiple processes are trying to use

Tags: windows, file-io, concurrency, java-5

I have 2 applications running in parallel, both doing the following:

- check for file not containing "processed"
- process the file and then rename it to filename+processed
- for every file, only one application shall use it (on a first come first served basis)

I get the files and I also lock them so the other application cannot process it. But when it comes to renaming the file I get a problem. To rename the file, wanted to use the File.renameTo function. However, for that to work, I have to release the lock on the file. But when I release the lock another process may try to use the file. Exactly that should not happen.

Is there any way to prevent the application B from using the file between application A releasing the lock and finishing renaming the file?

***EDIT***

Some more information:

- File creation if the file doesn't exist has to be prevented.
- The file will be processed RandomAccessFile (with read and write permission; this creates a new file if it doesn't exist).

Note: On linux, one can rename a file that is locked, so this problem doesn't occur there. However, on Windows a locked file cannot be renamed; I have to release the lock, then rename it. But the time, during which the lock is released creates enables other applications to see that the file is available and then they will try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows applications can do this using the [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which allows you to rename the file using the handle you already have open.  You probably can't do this natively from Java.

However, a more straightforward solution would be to rename the file (to `filename+processing`, for example) *before* you start processing it.  Whichever process successfully renames the file in this way is the one responsible for processing it and eventually renaming it to `filename+processed`.

Comment: If application A selects a file and renames it to filename+processing, and the same time the second application selects the same file and tries to rename it, one of them will create a new empty file. Then how can I prevent that?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for a rename operation to create a new file.  How are you doing the rename?

Comment: The rename not, but for the rename you need a File object. And since I need read and write permission then that will create the file if it doesn't exist anymore (if a second application renamed it in the meantime).

Comment: According to the documentation, creating a File object doesn't cause a new file to be created.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html and in particular note "Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system object such as a file or a directory."

Comment: Actually, I am using the RandomAccessFile for the processing. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sure, but you don't need to do that until after you've renamed the file.  Use a plain File object to do the rename, *then* open the RandomAccessFile.